# Debian Build-Depends on non-package binary

Tags: debian, packaging, rust

I am developing a Rust application and I want to provide packages for Debian. I have something similar to this configuration under `debian/controls`

```
Source: com.github.yourname.yourrepo
Section: x11
Priority: extra
Maintainer: Someone
Build-Depends: cargo,
               debhelper (>= 9),
               libgtk-3-dev,
               libglib2.0-dev
Standards-Version: 3.9.3

Package: com.github.yourname.yourrepo
Architecture: any
Depends: ${misc:Depends}, ${shlibs:Depends}
Description: SomeApp
Some app developed in Rust
```

But when I try to build it with `debuild` it complains that I don't have `cargo`. However, if I type `cargo` in my terminal it is present in the system. I guess the reason is that I didn't install the `cargo` package. And I don't want to force people to install it either, if they already have cargo. Is there a way to enforce having a dependency that is not a Debian package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to enforce a build- (or other) dependency which isn’t a Debian binary package. All the dependency, conflict etc. fields declare [relationships between *packages*](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html).

You *can* cheat by using `equivs` to create fake packages, if you want to use your own `cargo` instead of the packaged one, but then you won’t be able to check that your package builds correctly for other Debian users.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the `Build-Depends: ...` packages are only installed while building. That means end users will never see that list.

Instead, your `Depends: ...` is what gets automatically installed when the end users do:

```
apt install ./<package>.deb
```

So you can as well install the `cargo` package while building. The *only* reason for not doing so is if the build system cannot see a newer version of the package and that newer version is required. In that case, you'd have to create a `cargo` package yourself first and then use that *special* package in your build system (as mentioned by Stephen Kitt).